# How do I make query use exact post title

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

I am creating a custom search query in wordpress and the post title isn't matching. I want it to say the posttitle and the fullname have to be exact matches, or nothing should come up under the results. My Post_titles are all 5 digits numbers. But as of right now, I can type in the correct fullname but use any numbers that don't match the post title and it still shows up. Both need to be exact matches. Any suggestions on what to do here?

```
 <?php 
           /* Search Results */ 
 $patientid = '48392'; //Example only but must match exactly AND fullname should match exact too
 $fullname = 'John Doe'; //Example only. Exact match IS working on this but not AND

 $args = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'patients', 'post_title' => $patientid,
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key'     => 'fullname',
    'value'   => $fullname,
    'compare' => '=',
     ),
 ),);

  query_posts($args);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_page_by_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/), which allows you to query by Title, ID or Post Object. `query_posts` doesn't have the post title as a parameter and is deprecated (Use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead if you want to do a custom query).

```
$patient = get_page_by_title($patientid, 'OBJECT', 'patients'); // get the post object by title and cpt

if($patient) {
    $patient_fullname = get_post_meta($patient->ID, 'fullname', true); // get the post meta
    if($patient_fullname == $fullname) {
        // here both conditions are true.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I try it out and let you know.

Comment: It worked, but for some reason if a person is 00202 for a title , I can type 00201 and still shows. But it only does it between 00100 to 00202, any other number it will ring false. But its ok, I don't think there will be anyone with the same name within 100 digits. Thank you!

Comment: Its can return you drafts and trash too so make sure its dosent the case.. and filter this by the `$patient->post_status` make sure the status is publish.

Comment: Using `get_page_by_title($patientid, 'OBJECT', 'patients')` is the answer, though only shown in the code. I'll edit to fix this up.